# How to use matplotlib set_yscale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a function with Matplotlib, and I would like to set the y-axis to log-scale.

However, I keep getting an error using `set_yscale()`. After setting values for my x values and y values, I write

```
import matplotlib as plt

plot1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.set_xscale("log")
```

This results in the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_xscale'
```

So, I try

```
plot1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.set_xscale("log")
```

I get the same error.

How do you call this function?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you are calling your figure using `matplotlib.pyplot` directly you just need to call it using `plt.xscale('log')` or `plt.yscale('log')` instead of `plt.set_xscale('log')` or `plt.set_yscale('log')`

Only when you are using an axes instance like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

you call it using

```
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

Example:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.set_xscale('log')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.set_xscale('log')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_xscale'

>>> plt.xscale('log') # THIS WORKS
>>>
```

However

```
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
>>> ax.set_xscale('log')
>>>
```