# Change Y axis tick scale with log bar graph python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bar graph that is log scaled that I am trying to change the y ticks from 10^1, 10^2, etc., to whole numbers. I have tried setting the tick values manually, and tried setting the values from the data, and also setting the format to scalar. One thing I notice in all of the questions I am looking at is that my construction of the graph doesn't include `subplot`.

```
def confirmed_cases():
    x = df['Date']
    y = df['Confirmed']
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    plt.bar(x, y)
    plt.yscale('log')
#     plt.yticks([0, 100000, 250000, 500000, 750000, 1000000, 1250000])
#     plt.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
    plt.title('US Corona Cases By Date')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Confirmed Cases')
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: You may have to incorporate the `.gca()` call - try `plt.gca().yscale('log')`

Comment: Do I need to import `gca`? I get this `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'yscale'` which suggests I should change the structure of the function, correct?

Comment: Apologies, I may not be reading the documentation correctly. There's a call `.set_yscale('log)` that is specific to axes, and I don't think you need to call gca for that https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale.html What happens if you try `plt.set_yscale('log')`

Comment: `module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_yscale'`

Comment: Perhaps try and follow the answer presented in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193976/how-to-use-matplotlib-set-yscale In your original post you mentioned that other questions were relating to subplots; matplotlib has a lot of different ways you can set up axes and subplots, making it a bit difficult to know which way is the best. One side effect of that is that you may need to redo how the plot is set up and follow the subsequent rules/functions of that particular method. Anyway, have a read of that and see if it answers your question

Comment: I'm trying to follow but I'm getting errors such as can't be string, must not be list, must be 3 digit integer, and `num must be 1 <= num <= 0, not 0` when using `100` to see what happens when using a 3 digit integer. I have tried using the `subplot` but it's not creating the set figure size while still keeping the original y ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few issues:

- The formatter needs to be placed at the `yaxis` of the `ax`. Use`plt.gca()` to get the current `ax`. Note that there is no function `plt.get_yaxis()`.
- The scalar formatter starts using exponential notation for large numbers. To prevent that, `set_powerlimits((m,n))` makes sure the powers are only shown for values outside the range `10**m` and `10**n`.
- In a log scale, major ticks are used for values `10**n` for integer `n`. The other ticks or minor ticks, at positions `k*10**n` for k from 2 to 9. If there are only a few major ticks visible, the minor ticks can also get a tick label. To suppress both the minor tick marks and their optional labels, a `NullFormatter` can be used.
- Avoid using a tick at zero for a log-scale axis. Log(0) is minus infinity.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.bar(np.arange(100), np.random.geometric(1/500000, 100))
plt.yscale('log')
formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter()
formatter.set_powerlimits((-6,9))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.NullLocator())
plt.yticks([100000, 250000, 500000, 750000, 1000000, 1250000])
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]